# How can I make two MVC routes starting with different path names use the same controller in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have the following routes:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "One",
      url: "admin/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Two",
      url: "home/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Is there a way that I can combine these routes into just one route where the they both direct to the "Home" controller?

Comment: Hi Jason. The heading may sound like a duplicate but my questions is different and also the question you link to didn't have an accepted answer :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default2",
           url: "{section}/{id}",
           defaults: new {section="home" ,controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

works for me

answer on comment.
what a problem add the constraint?

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default2",
           url: "{section}/{id}",
           defaults: new { section = "home", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           constraints: new { section = "admin|home" }
       );
```

Comment: maxs87 - The problem is I just want it to work if the routes start with home or admin :-(   I don't want it to work with other words.

Comment: @Gemma he added a constraint so that it is either admin or home

Comment: I saw the addition of a constraint but I am wondering is this an efficient way to do it. It feels like I'm letting everything in and then checking to see if it matches. Is there not an option that would just filter with "admin|home" at the front-end.  I'm not questioning this may work just wondering about any other options. Also wondering how this would work if I ran the routechecker that Phil Hack created.